# Count the number of arguments actually passed to a python function

Tags: python, function, count, arguments, default

I would like to retrieve the number of arguments that have been passed to a Python function. In fact I am writting a Matlab code in Python and in Matlab, the code line is :

```
if (nargin > 2)
    ...
end
```

I would like to do the same thing in Python with a function that have this form : `def my_func(a,b,c=3,d=4, ...):`

When calling it, I would be able to retrieve the number of passed arguments, for instance :

`my_func(1,2)` would return 2

`my_func(1,2,3)` would return 3

`my_func(1,2,3,4)` would return 4 etc.

I have seen some topics but only giving the number of arguments and description of the function, and not the number of arguments passed when calling it in a script.

I hope that I am clear in explaining my issue.

Best regards,
MOCHON Rémi

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Although this approach might work for some cases - put a check explicitly in your code that how many values received are exactly equal to the default values specified :)

Answer (score 2):

Below code will work for you

```
def param_count(*args):
    return len(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you ask for, but a simple way to achieve this is to count the number of `args` and `kwargs` using a decorator, and then pass it to the function.

The decorator will look like this:

```py
def count_nargin(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        nargin = len(args) + len(kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs, nargin=nargin)
    return inner
```

You will then have to modify your function to accept the `nargin` parameter:

```py
@count_nargin
def my_func(a,b,c=3,d=4,nargin=None):
    print(nargin)
```

For example, calling the above function returns:

```py
>>> my_func(1,2)
2

>>> my_func(1,2,3)
3
```